# <center> is not supported in HTML5 but its still working. How?

Tags: html5, google-chrome

`<center>` tag to make texts centered is not supported in HTML5 but its still working in the latest version of chrome.

Is Chrome making up for the mistake or is it still supporting the deprecated tags along with the new HTML5 tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers are *very* forgiving. They will take badly mangled HTML and do their best to render a web page with it. In the case of using deprecated or invalid tags, they will typically honor them even though they are invalid. This *may* cause your page to be rendered in quirks mode which can cause other problems, however, so using them should be avoided. This also doesn't apply when support for a tag is completely removed like [Firefox 23 removing support for the `<blink>` tag](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/163291-firefox-23-finally-kills-the-blink-tag-removes-ability-to-turn-off-javascript-introduces-new-logo) (thank goodness).

Comment: @John "quirks mode" only exists in IE and occurs when a doctype is missing, not on invalid HTML.